# Why is my Rails App faster on Heroku than on my Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

When I was developing my Rails app I noticed that it got extremely slow as soon as I included some background File creation via Amazon S3.

When I uploaded my site to Heroku the load time dropped a lot.
On my local server a page load takes about ~12s, on Heroku just ~1s.

Why does my app run that much slower on my local computer?
Does the Heroku server have a faster connection to the Amazon S3 servers?

Comment: Different Rails environments? You typically use `development` locally and `production` on Heroku.

Comment: Does that make a noticeable difference in speed?

Comment: Yes, for example, `development` reloads your code to reflect changes while you are developing (so you don't have to restart `rails server` every time), whereas `production` uses caching to avoid reloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to your last question, yes, Heroku almost certainly has a faster connection to the AWS servers. According to the Heroku support [page](https://www.heroku.com/policy/security):

> Heroku’s physical infrastructure is hosted and managed within Amazon’s secure data centers and utilize the Amazon Web Service (AWS) technology

Since they are both physically near and probably use the same datacenters as Amazon, any uploading / downloading to Amazon servers will be fast.

EDIT:

And as @Stefan noted, running rails in production mode speeds up a lot of stuff, including assets serving. You can try to run your server locally in production mode to see if that's the issue by running

```
$ rails s -e production
```

Comment: Thanks for that precise answer :-)